# unable to determine valid execution date from repeat interval

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/mon/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

BEGIN

dbms_scheduler.create_schedule (
    schedule_name   => 'schedule_meter_reading',
    start_date      => '31-OCT-2023 20:00:00',
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=5',
    end_date        => '31-OCT-2023 21:00:00',
    comments        => 'repeated every 5 minutes'
   
);

END;

BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.drop_schedule (schedule_name => 'schedule_meter_reading');
END;


BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_program(program_name => 'add_meter_reading', program_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', program_action => 'BEGIN show_time; END;'
    , enabled => true, comments => 'Reading data from the meter');
END;


BEGIN
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'Add_reading', program_name => 'add_meter_reading', start_date => systimestamp, repeat_interval => 'schedule_meter_reading', enabled => true);
END;
```

Trying to build
schedule
program
job.job.
When trying to create a job, I receive an error:

> report report -
>  ORA-27419: unable to determine valid execution
> date from repeat interval
>  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_ISCHED", line
> 175
>  ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER", line 485
>  ORA-06512: at
> line 2

Comment: I changed it. But the problem remained the same. But the problem remained the same

Comment: Stop relying on implicit casts from strings to timestamps; instead use a `TIMESTAMP` literal. `start_date => TIMESTAMP '2023-10-31 20:00:00', end_date => TIMESTAMP '2023-10-31 21:00:00',`

Comment: Also, why did you drop the schedule immediately after you created it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set the format using a session parameter, you must set `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` instead of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. This is because the `DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_SCHEDULER.START_DATE` and `END_DATE` parameters are `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` types, not `DATE` types.

But I strongly recommend you follow MT0's recommendation and use date and timestamp literals, like this:

```
start_date => timestamp '2023-10-31 20:00:00'
```

Date and timestamp literals have many advantages over strings converted to dates or timestamps: the ISO-8601 format is unambiguous and sorts correctly as a string, the values are treated as literals by the compiler (which helps the optimizer in a few rare cases), and the months are not ambiguous (the month abbreviation "OCT" does not work for every language and calendar). Unless your program is displaying data, you should avoid relying on session or system formats.formats.

---

To answer your new question, you can change the setting for the entire database by changing `ALTER SESSION` to `ALTER DATABASE`. But that change would almost certainly be a blunder. System format parameters are frequently overridden by session parameters, which will depend on what IDE you are using, which may read from your local computer's region settings. If you frequently change and depend on system parameters for formatting, you will create weird scenarios where the code might work for an English-speaking American who uses TOAD, but the code will fail for a French-speaking Canadian who uses Oracle SQL Developer.

Use literals to avoid date format hell.

Answer (score 0):

You are using dashes "-" in your create_schedule command, but your NLS format has slashes "/"